# Flood Fill with Pattern Image Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

**I have had success in flood fill algorithm with color**.

This is *something i have been trying it works well in filling the color* 
but had **no success in filling the Image** .

**the code for flood filling the color**

```
if (!_color)
    @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:NSInternalInconsistencyException 
                                   reason:@"Please set fill color" 
                                 userInfo:nil];

CGColorRef colorRef = [_color CGColor];
const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(colorRef);

NSString* colorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"rgb(%f,%f,%f)", components[0]*255.0f,
                         components[1]*255.0f, components[2]*255.0f];

if (!PixelSetColor(fc_wand, [colorString UTF8String]))
    @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:NSInternalInconsistencyException reason:@"Unable to set wand color" userInfo:nil];

PixelIterator* iterator = NULL;
PixelWand** pixels = NULL;
size_t x;
iterator = NewPixelRegionIterator(magick_wand, _touchCoords.x*scale, _touchCoords.y*scale, 1, 1);
pixels = PixelGetNextIteratorRow(iterator,&x);
bc_wand = pixels[0];

channel = ParseChannelOption("rgba");

//  The bordercolor=bc_wand (with fuzz of 20 applied) is replaced 
// by the fill colour=fc_wand starting at the given coordinate - in this case 0,0.
// Normally the last argument is MagickFalse so that the colours are matched but
// if it is MagickTrue then it floodfills any pixel that does *not* match 
// the target color
status = MagickFloodfillPaintImage(magick_wand, channel, fc_wand, _tolerance, bc_wand, _touchCoords.x*scale, _touchCoords.y*scale, MagickFalse);
if (status == MagickFalse) {
    ThrowWandException(magick_wand);
}

size_t my_size;
unsigned char * my_image = MagickGetImageBlob(magick_wand,&my_size);
NSData* data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:my_image length:my_size];
free(my_image);

UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
//[data release];

[self setImage:image];
//[image release];
if(_mwDelegate)
    [_mwDelegate imageViewDidFinishedProcessing:self];
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Color with pattern image didn't work .

Comment: Not sure what this Magick library does, but it's pretty simple to fill something with a pattern using native iOS methods. The UIColor class can read a pattern directly using colorWithPatternImage, and you can use that to fill shapes created with UIBezierPath.

Comment: @AnnaDickinson thanks but I am filling a part of image with image .When I get color components i.e r,g,b that we get from color with pattern image I always get red color i.e 255,0,0